# Gradle Build issue while using remote repository

Tags: gradle

Issues which I am facing are related to gradle build. I would like to explain what I am doing.
I created a remote repository on a remote server and I am able to access it from browser (the shared folder under which I have kept some dependency Jars).
Now I want to use that remote repository in my build.gradle (like a remote maven repository) and so I added snippet like this:

```
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  repositories{
     maven {
            //URL of the remote repository
            url "http://IP:Port/SharedPath"
     }
  }
  dependencies {
         //Dependencies which are there in remote repository.
         compile group: "GroupName", name: "DependencyName", version: "Version"
         compile group: "GroupName1", name: "DependencyName1", version: ""
   }
```

When I am running gradle build, I am getting error message like this:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
    > Could not find :cachedb.jar:.
        Searched in the following locations:
            http://IP:Port/SharedPath/GroupName/DependencyName/Version/DependencyName-Version.pom
            http://IP:Port/SharedPath/GroupName/DependencyName/Version/DependencyName-Version.jar
        Required by:
        :site-export-tool:unspecified
    > Could not find :cachejdbc:.
        Searched in the following locations:
            http://IP:Port/SharedPath/GroupName1/DependencyName1//DependencyName1-.pom
            http://IP:Port/SharedPath/GroupName1/DependencyName1//DependencyName1-.jar
        Required by:
        :site-export-tool:unspecified
```

I don't understand why it is searching the file at the path: **url / GroupName / DependencyName / Version / DependencyName-Version.jar**

While it should check for the jar at the path in URL only and not under some folder structure on the name of **GroupName** and **DependencyName** and so on... or simply say, I dont want to pass GroupName (it is possible?)
Please NOTE: I tried this also:

```
  compile files ('lib/DependencyName-Version.jar',
        'lib/DependencyName1.jar')
```

Please be notified that, When I am keeping those dependencies in my local system and defining them in **flatDir**, I am **NOT** facing any issue in that case.

I am trying to use remote repository because we in our organization want to use a centralized location. 
Please let me know if I need to do anything with gradle configuration or gradle version which I am using (gradle 2.13) or anything in build.gradle only, I dont understand what is wrong which I am doing here. Stuck from past 2 days :-(

Thanks a ton in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because gradle expects standard maven repository structure when you use `maven {url ".."}`, which is

```
/$groupId[0]/../${groupId[n]/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version.$extension
```

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final

Either follow that structure or you can try using Ivy repository with custom layout.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:defining_custom_pattern_layout_for_an_ivy_repository

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply :-) I will now make my directory in this order so that it works :-)